# how can i redirect a user to a different server with python?

Tags: python, http, redirect, pcap

I'm trying to write a script which will monitor packets (using pypcap) and redirect certain URLs/IPs to something I choose. I know I could just edit the hosts file, but that won't work because I'm not an admin.

I'm thinking that CGI might be useful, but this one has really got me confused.

EDIT:
sorry if it sounded malicious or like a MITM attack. The reason I need this is because I have an (old) application which grabs a page from a site, but the domain has changed recently causing it to not function anymore. I didn't write the application, so I can't just change the domain it accesses.

I basically need to accomplish what can be done by editing the hosts file without having access to it.

Comment: Everything after "packets" makes no sense. On which network layer do you want to redirect traffic?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a man-in-the-middle attack unless you provide a more lucid description...

Comment: So you want to modify the contents of packets being sent between two other hosts...hrrrm, why is this something you want to do?

Comment: Responding GET request with "Moved Permanently", then specifying the new host/domain, would satisfy your needs?

Comment: How are you able to monitor packets if you're not an admin?  Doing this at the packet level is going to be MUCH more headache than it is worth. This is something that needs to be parsed at the application level; I'd completely rethink the approach. Read your web servers documentation on redirection.

Answer (score 0):

pypcap needs administrative rights, so this is not an option.

And you don't have access to the pcs internals, to the source code or to the webserver.

There are a few options left:

1. Modify the host name in the applications files with a hexeditor and disassembler.
2. Modify the loaded application in memory with [Cheat Engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/) and other memory tools.
3. Start the application in a virtual environment which can modify os api calls. A modified wine might be able to do this.
4. Modify the request between the pc and the webserver with a (transparent)proxy / modified router.

If the application supports the usage of proxies, it might be the easiest solution to set up a local [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) with a [redirector](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors).